# Slide-out menu css only

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I am trying to make a css-only slide-out menu, which can be slid out and back, see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EZ8SK/1/ here. Now I'd like to combine the Handlers into one.
I tried doing so with radio or checkboxes, but I could not get it to work, I guess I overlooked something.

**CSS**

```
#wrapper                  { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
#header-wrapper           { width: 100%; height: 56px; position: relative }
#header                   { width: 100%; height: 56px; background: #111; position: absolute; }

        #content-wrapper  { width: 100%; background: #333; }
            #left-nav     { width: 200px; height: 100%; background: #555; float: left; }
            #right-nav    { width: 300px; height: 100%; background: #555; float: right; }

    #left-nav             { margin-top: -392px; transition-duration: .4s }
    #left-nav:target      { margin-top: -56px }
    #nav-menu > .menu-item > .menu-item-link { display: block; padding: 20px; width: calc(200px - (2*20px)); }      
    #right-menu > .menu-item > .menu-item-link { display: block; padding: 20px; width: calc(300px - (2*20px)); }      
    .menu-item-link:hover { background: #222 }

    #menu-slideout        { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; color: #fff; }
    #last-item            { cursor: pointer; display: block; }
    #last-item:hover      { background: #222; cursor: pointer }
    #last-item-back:hover { background: #222; cursor: pointer }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="header-wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="menu-slideout">
                <div id="left-nav">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul id="nav-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="" class="menu-item-link">Menüpunkt</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#left-nav" class="menu-item-link" id="last-item">Einblenden</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#" class="menu-item-link" id="last-item-back">Ausblenden</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be easy with just a touch of JavaScript, simply adding something like `<a onclick="togglePos(this)">` around the last `li` element and using

```js
function togglePos(obj) { 
    obj.style.webkitTransform = (obj.style.webkitTransform == "translateY(-392px)") ?
        "translateY(0px)" : "translateY(-392px)";
    obj.style.transform = (obj.style.transform == "translateY(-392px)") ?
        "translateY(0px)" : "translateY(-392px)";
}
```

but I withheld all of those feelings and worked for a while to come up with this technique:

```css
/* CSS */
ul {
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-90px);
    transform:translateY(-90px);
    transition: 1s;
}
ul li {
    transition: 1s;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999px;
    left: -999px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul {
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
    transform:translateY(0px);
}
label {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML (for demo) -->
<input type="checkbox" id="toggler">
<ul id='dropDown'>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Second to last one</li>
    <label for="toggler"><li>Last one</li></label>
</ul>
<div>Other content</div>
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jmM4z/249/)

The result is surprisingly simple if you know what is going on. You can place the `input` in front of the object you want to affect and put the label with the `for="toggler"` around the element you want to use to toggle the `translateY`. Using transform is more performant than using `margin` or `top`.

Sorry for not applying it to your situation in particular, I am not sure what all you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I missed out.